# Sharing phone's internet connection on laptop without the help of USB cable

Tags: android, bluetooth

At the moment, I use my phone's internet connection on my laptop by using a USB cable. How do I set things up to use internet using my phone without the USB cable. So, that I can get rid of the USB cable and use Bluetooth instead?

I am using an android phone and I want to use my phones 3g data to give my laptop an internet connection in remote locations where I don't have wifi access.  Plus my laptop doesn't have wifi anyway, just bluetooth.

So basically, how do I configure ubuntu so it can use the internet made available for my phones bluetooth connection which passes through the 3g connection to my computer?

Comment: What phone are using? What OS does it run? Does the phone support creating a wifi hotspot?

Comment: While the [**question is with too little information**](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/9096/questions-with-too-little-information), I'd suggest you add more in-detail including what @Jobin has asked. This will help us to assist you better. :)

Comment: Why do you need to use the internet using Bluetooth when you already have an android with WiFi hostspot which you can simply configure and connect using your lap's WiFi. ?

Comment: @AzkerM, 2 reasons for that.  1. I don't have wifi on my laptop.  2. I want to use my phones 3g via bluetooth to give my laptop an internet connection where no wifi is available.

Comment: Well, now **bluetooth** actually make sense and its good that you've edited your question by adding those necessary information. I've never used nor have I seen anyone experimenting this in Linux but Windows. I hope an expert will assist you on this. :/

Comment: Why are you asking us about the version of android that supports bluetooth tethering? Why instead not asking us "how I configure bluetooth tethering using bluetooth in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your phone needs to support Bluetooth tethering. Where to find this setting depends on your phone. If you happen to use Cyanogenmod, it would be under Settings > Wireless & Networks > More > Tethering & portable hotspot > Bluetooth tethering. On other Android flavors you would need to look around. If you don't have this setting, you might be able to get it to work by installing an app – Google Play has a few that claim to do the job, though I haven't tried any myself.

Having made sure your phone supports Bluetooth tethering, get Blueman (from the Ubuntu repositories). With that you can pair your phone and computer and then use it for Internet connection.

Comment: I can see an option to switch on usb tethering, but I can't see bluetooth tethering.  I can only switch on bluetooth on the phone.

Comment: I've edited my response, including some information on how to check if Bluetooth tethering is available or how to get it.

Comment: I hope that you have a recent phone & laptop which support the recent version of the Bluetooth protocol with higher speed. Or you won't be able to take advantage of the 3G speed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called USB Tethering in android.

Goto

`Settings` --> `Wireless & Networks` --> `Internet tethering`

or

`Settings` -> `Wireless settings` -> `Tethering` -> `Tethering USB...`

It changes based on the version of android you are using... Switch ON this tethering after plugin the android mobile to the laptop.

You can also use WiFi tethering.

Comment: That's usb tethering, which I currently use, I want to get rid of the usb cable and do the whole thing using bluetooth.

Comment: why don't you use WIFI Tethering?.

Comment: 2 reasons.  1. Because I need to use my 3g connection, you can't get wifi everywhere.  2. I don't want to carry around a usb cable, I want to do this via bluetooth.

Comment: You are misunderstood... you activated WIFI Tethering means your mobile will act as a modem+wifi router's role. This method uses your phone's internet connection(2g or 3g whatever) to your laptop which is connected to your mobile via WIFI Hotspot teathering.